Trouble Programming ATTINY1616 with Arduino Nano via UPDI: No Communication
I'm trying to program a board I designed with an ATTINY1616. The schematic is shown in the photo. I'm trying to connect an Arduino Nano. +5V and GND are shared, while the UPDI pin is connected to the Nano's D6 with a 470Ω resistor in series and a 10kΩ pull-up. Is there any mistake? I can't establish communication. I have, of course, flashed jtag2updi from https://github.com/SpenceKonde/jtag2updi.


Other than showing us the schematic, there is not much information you tell us. What "no communication" means? What is your configuration setup on Arduino IDE Tools -> Programmer?

You could also consider the following statement from the SpenceKonde link you have quoted above as a warning and look at the alternatives: "This tool is not recommended anymore". I use a simple USB/UART adaptor, a diode and a resistor for UPDI programming of the new series AVR chips.

State also what connections you make between your Nano and header H3 on your ATtiny1616 board when attempting a program upload.

Sometimes loose connections or poor contact can prevent proper communication.
Check if the 470Ω resistor is placed between D6 of the Nano and the UPDI pin on the ATTINY1616, with no breaks in the line. Since, it's a custom-made board, there may be some manufacturing errors. Please check your PCB thoroughly with a multimeter. The following contents may help in this regard:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxlqhZVOdNI
https://www.pcbway.com/blog/2/Modern_PCB_testing_strategies.html
Also, check your power supply. If the ATTINY1616 isn't getting enough power, programming might fail. If possible, check the voltage at the ATTINY1616 during programming.
